# Stop Sound playing on Node in SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have the following code for a gesture recogniser that plays a horn, when tapped, and stops when it is released:

```
@objc func didPressHorn(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)

    if sender.state == .began {

        if (wasNodeTapped(node: hornNode!, tapLocation: tapLocation)) {
            hornNode!.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(hornSound, waitForCompletion: false), forKey: "Horn")
            hornPlaying = true
        }

    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        if hornPlaying {
            // tried all the possible solutions, but the sound won't stop
            hornNode?.removeAction(forKey: "Horn")
            hornNode?.removeAllActions()
            hornNode?.isPaused = true
            hornSound.volume = 0
            hornPlaying = false
            print("Horn off") //gets printed!
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying all possible solutions (that I know), and also the print statements gets printed. However, the sound will not switch off. Do you have an idea, why?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if its the best idea/pratice, but you could try: `self. hornNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()`

Hope it can help!

Comment: thanks for your response! Actually, thats pretty weird: first it looks like it's working, because the horn goes on and after releasing it stops as intended. However, if it tap it again, nothing happens, so the horn stays off.... do you have an idea why?

Comment: ah, that was because now somehow the volume = 0 and isPaused = true statements are working. When I remove then, the horn works as intended :) However, I'm still wondering, why the other statements don't work... do you have an idea, why?